# 2010 - Auto select resource in Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, resources

Just a note: Within my deployment I am unable to use any external programs such as Designer or Visual Studio, coding is always a happy choice though.

I have the need to create a calendar that works booking a room, my initial solution was to create a calendar and have it utilise Resource Reservation's so that users could check if the room was already booked. Unfortunately the person that set this all off needs there to be one calendar per room, and as such I am looking for a way to have the Newform automatically select the resource while hiding the field from the user for simplicity in the UI.

Thanks for all your advice.